# Why is the ringTone <Dial> attribute a country code?

Tags: twilio

Why is the ringTone  attribute a country code? Are ringtones standardized by country? If so, is there somewhere I can hear what each ring tone sounds like? I'd like to avoid having to test each one within Twilio if possible.

Comment: Yes, different countries uses different signals in their phone system. Historically it depended on the equipment, but today it mostly digital. Not only the dial tone, but the signal for ringing, busy, and information also differs.

Comment: Nice, thanks. I did end up finding a video that plays some of the tones: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6dFBbQkg1J4